# Store API response in two different model objects using Realm and Parcel

Tags: android, realm, parcel

Sorry about confusing title but here is the scenario,

There is an API response like below,

```
"API_RESPONSE": {
  "id": "12345",
  "name": "Michael",
  "surname": "J.",
  "inventory"{
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

And I need to model this response with these two RealmObjets,

```
@Parcel(implementations = { ModelARealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.FIELD,
        analyze = { ModelA.class})
public class ModelA extends RealmObject {

    public Inventory inventory;
}

@Parcel(implementations = { ModelBRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.FIELD,
        analyze = { ModelB.class })
public class ModelB extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String surname;
}
```

So here is the question, how can I model the API response with using these two objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApiResponse {
    @SerializedName("API_RESPONSE")
    public ApiResponsePayload payload;
}

public class ApiResponsePayload {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("surname")
    public String surname;
    @SerializedName("inventory")
    public Inventory inventory;

    public ApiResponsePayload() { // for gson
    }

    public ApiResponsePayload(ModelA modelA, ModelB modelB) {
        this.id = modelA.getId();
        this.name = modelA.getName();
        this.surname = modelA.getSurname();
        this.inventory = modelB.getInventory();
    }
}
```